# word form activex listbox items not printing to pdf

Tags: vba, printing, ms-word, export-to-pdf

How do i get an active-x listbox that is not active and where no item was selected by the user to be printed to pdf?

create a new worddocument, add three activex listboxes
copy following macro in the vba-editor and run by hitting f5

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    ListBox1.AddItem "one"
    ListBox1.AddItem "two"
    ListBox1.AddItem "three"  
  
    ListBox2.AddItem "a"
    ListBox2.AddItem "b"
    ListBox2.AddItem "c"

    ListBox3.AddItem "x"
    ListBox3.AddItem "y"
    ListBox3.AddItem "z"
    ListBox3.Activate
End Sub
```

if i export this worddoc to PDF, it prints me two empty listboxes, although it shows them populated in word, only the third, x y z is populated in the pdf.

if, before exporting to pdf i select "two" in the first listbox, it prints me a correctly populated listbox and the selected item in blue, the second listbox stays empty (although populated in word)

(the same behaviour when using MS word export to pdf or when using foxit reader pdf plugin in word to create the pdfs)

Comment: That is because only ListBox3 has been activated. Just activate the others in your code and you'll have them all populated.

Comment: they are populated on screen in windows, but are empty when exported/printed to PDF.  there can only be one item active, so activating them all is not the solution :(

Comment: In the code only one is activated at a time. Because each one has been activated the values then get exported to pdf. I don't make suggestions I haven't tested.

Comment: How about using [content control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.contentcontrol) items instead of active-x listbox?

Comment: unfortunatly i don't get the listbox to print as i need, i'll work around using regular checkboxes instead of a  multiselectlistbox with liststyle set to frmliststyleoption;  thank you both for helping!